# How to prevent Internet Explorer from scrolling up when clicking on Image Map with SVG?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, svg

I have an image map with SVG. On click event of any shape on the image map, I show a div element with some data which can then be closed by the user. If the image height exceeds the window size and user has to scroll down to view it, the click event on a shape behaves unpredictably on Internet Explorer. Depending on the scroll position, it may either behave as desired (i.e. show the div element with data) or just scrolls up to the top. I have looked deep in Stackoverflow and elsewhere on Google with no solution.

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/awfzcf0d/6/

Alternately here is the entire html page - uses jquery hosted on google cdn (save as html using any text editor and open in IE)

```
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Image Map Click Event Does Not Fire in IE, when page is scrolled down. Instead the page scrolls to top</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



<body>
<style>

    #floorplanIM         {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 77%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #floorplanIM svg {
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    rect{
        fill: #ccc;
        fill-opacity: 0.9;
    }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("rect").click(function (e) {
            $('#roominfo').css({display: 'none' });
            $('#roominfo').css({ left: e.pageX, top: e.pageY , position: 'absolute', display:'block' });

        });

        $('#closeme').click(function () { $("#roominfo").hide(); });

    }); //end of $(document).ready

</script>
<p>Click event on rectangular image map (overlayed on boy's right hand) displays a square (div) on first click. 
Click 'Close' to hide the square (div). On scrolling down and clicking again on the image map, it does not fire the click event to show the div; 
It simply scrolls the page up; Works OK in Chrome.</p>
<figure id="floorplanIM">
    <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?-->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 802 620" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" xml:space="preserve">
    <image id="img3" width="802" height="620" xlink:href="http://bawandinesh.name/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Confusion.jpg"></image>
<rect x="-25" y="-25" rx="0" ry="0" width="50" height="50" name="room_1006" transform="translate(555 456.76499939) scale(2.0784313725 2.2080392277)"></rect>

</svg>
</figure>
<div id="roominfo" style="display: none; width: 100px; height:100px; background-color:antiquewhite; color: black; position: absolute; border: solid 1px #111;">

    <div class="delete_link"><a id="closeme" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a></div>


</div>

</article>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: I tested your fiddle on IE 9-11 and could not reproduce your result.  I am not sure if this will help as I have not really worked with image maps in the past.. but try adding a return false; to the end of the rect.click function.

Comment: @tdanielcox: You need to scroll down the result window and then click on the image map (grey square). Fiddle is designed for viewport height 768px so may behave differently on a higher resolution monitor. I had already tried adding return false and it does not help. Tried it again in the fiddle. Same result.